# R - Can't connect to local MySQL Db

Tags: mysql, r

I am trying to connect to a local MySQL db, but am getting the following error.

> Error in .local(drv, ...) :
>
> Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)

The code I am using is as follows:

```
dbConnect (RMySQL::MySQL(),
           username = "root",
           password = "",
           host = "127.0.0.1",
           port = 3306,
           dbname = "history")
```

I have tried connecting to the MySQL db I have on AWS and have no problems. I have also tried changing the host address to an empty string, and to "localHost". Any support someone can provide is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an error? I think first thing you should check is password.

Comment: The following is the error I am getting. I have played with the password. That does not seem to be the issue

Error in .local(drv, ...) :

Failed to connect to database: Error: Can't initialize character set unknown (path: compiled_in)